# Count unique values for previous rows in sorted table

Tags: r

I'm trying to count the unique row values for a sorted table. So if I had a table like:

```
 data('chickwts')
 chickwts[order(chickwts$weight),]
```

I'd like to be able to retrieve the total number of unique feeds for the preceding rows. Therefore, if I wanted `weight < 150` as my cutoff, I would get `feed count = 2`. Ideally I would be able to generate a column that also keeps track of this count throughout the rows and plot this number against the `weight` in this case.

I know I can pre-select/subset with grepl:

```
chickwts$seed=ifelse(grepl("seed",chickwts$feed),TRUE,FALSE)*1
chickwts[order(chickwts$weight), ]
```

I know I can use `unique` to get unique names, but I'm having trouble putting these together to get that final count column.

Comment: chickwts should be one of the base datasets.:https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/00Index.html

Comment: Minimal - comes from simple dataset available to everyone. Complete - if you can answer the question for chickwts, then it will answer it for my much larger dataframe.

Comment: You fixed it fine. Sorry to be so particular, but you'll get that way after spending enough time on SO. We're trying to improve question quality right now, nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data("chickwts")    
chickwts <- chickwts[order(chickwts$weight),]

# Using < 150 as a cutoff
cat("if you meant 1 column giving the count to all rows, based on < 150")
chickwts$count_less_than_150 <- length(unique(chickwts$feed[chickwts$weight < 150]))

cat("if you meant 2 columns giving the count to all rows, based on < 150 or > 150")
chickwts$count_lt_150 <- length(unique(chickwts$feed[chickwts$weight < 150]))
chickwts$count_ge_150 <- length(unique(chickwts$feed[chickwts$weight >= 150]))

cat("if you meant 1 column giving the count to all rows, based on < 150 or >= 150")
chickwts$count <- NA
chickwts$count[chickwts$weight < 150]  <- length(unique(chickwts$feed[chickwts$weight < 150]))
chickwts$count[chickwts$weight >= 150] <- length(unique(chickwts$feed[chickwts$weight >= 150]))
```

Comment: That works, is there any way to extend this to use the current row's weight as the cutoff?

Comment: @desc I'm a little unclear what you mean, if you provide an example of what you'd want the output to look like then I can do that

Comment: No worries, JackieJR's `lapply` solution below takes care of the conditional third column.

Answer (score 2):

```
data("chickwts")
chickwts <-  chickwts[order(chickwts[,"weight"]),]
chickwts[,"unique.feed"] <- unlist(lapply(chickwts[,"weight"], function(n) with(chickwts, length(unique(feed[weight < n])))))
```

1. Use all the weights in an `lapply` function
2. Check which weights are less than weight of current row `weight < n`
3. Get the corresponding feeds of weights less than that of current row `feed[weight < n]`
4. Get the unique feeds and count how many unique there are with `unique` and `length`.
5. `unlist` them as we want a vector.

Comment: +1 - @JackeJR, that perfectly answers my question in the comments above. Hack-R did answer the original question, so I'm sticking with that as the official answer, but thank you!